# SQL Server 2012 DBCC memorystatus has wrong information. How can I correct it?

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows, memory, dbcc

I have a Windows 7 64-bit machine with 16GB ram, 24GB pagefile, 500GB HD and SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition 64-bit running on it.

*With 5 minutes of starting up*, it routinely uses all my virtual memory and triggers warnings on my machine i.e. ProcessExplorer says sqlservr.exe is using Private Bytes of 38GB, Virtual Size of 61GB.

I believe the issue results from mis-information that I can see when I run DBCC MemoryStatus command, which indicates that the **Available Virtual Memory is 8,763,135,270,912. This number is at least 8TB**. Other stats returned by the command appear to be accurate.

Does anyone know how the DBCC MemoryStatus command gets this number and how I might correct it? I think this would affect how much virtual memory it would try to allocate.

Answer (score 2):

[x86-64 Virtual Address Space Details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details):

> Although virtual addresses are 64 bits wide in 64-bit mode, current implementations (and all chips known to be in the planning stages) do not allow the entire virtual address space of 264 bytes (16 EB) to be used. This would be approximately four billion times the size of virtual address space on 32-bit machines. Most operating systems and applications will not need such a large address space for the foreseeable future, so implementing such wide virtual addresses would simply increase the complexity and cost of address translation with no real benefit. AMD therefore decided that, in the first implementations of the architecture, only the least significant 48 bits of a virtual address would actually be used in address translation (page table lookup).1
>
> In addition, the AMD specification requires that bits 48 through 63 of any virtual address must be copies of bit 47 (in a manner akin to sign extension), or the processor will raise an exception.1 Addresses complying with this rule are referred to as "canonical form."1 Canonical form addresses run from 0 through 00007FFF'FFFFFFFF, and from FFFF8000'00000000 through FFFFFFFF'FFFFFFFF, for a total of 256 TB of usable virtual address space. This is still approximately 64,000 times the virtual address space on 32-bit machines.
>
> [...]
>
> **The first versions of Windows for x64 did not even use the full 256 TB; they were restricted to just 8 TB of user space and 8 TB of kernel space**. Windows did not support the entire 48-bit address space until Windows 8.1

There you have it. As the OS supports more than the default 8TB VA, it has become necessary to report in the DBCC MEMORY_STATUS *how much* is the OS actually supporting. Your OS is still the classical 8TB flavor.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in `Available Virtual Memory is 8,763,135,270,912. This number is at least 8TB` actually starting from SQL Server 2012 this new feature has been introduced in SQL Server 2012 DBCC MEMORYSTATUS output. Below is output of memorystatus on my system

```
Process/System Counts                    Value
---------------------------------------- --------------------
Available Physical Memory                1886949376
Available Virtual Memory                 8781736599552
Available Paging File                    10989400064
Working Set                              135262208
Percent of Committed Memory in WS        61
Page Faults                              15069059
System physical memory high              1
System physical memory low               0
Process physical memory low              0
```

Before giving information about actual memory distribution it gives information about current status of system. SQL Server 64 bit has theoretically has VAS of around 8 TB this is basically virtual address space. All process which would run on SQL Server would see this much VAS so if system is pointing out available Virtual Memory as **almost** 8 TB I dont think there is anything to worry about it. This is system pointing to amount of VAS visible to any process running on 64 bit SQL Server instance.

Please always use below query to see SQL Server memory utilization because task manager only shows process private bytes and if SQL Server service account has locked pages in memory privilege it would not show correct value. As a fact task manager would not show memory allocated through AWE API

```
select
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024)Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024 )Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB,
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024 )Total_VAS_in_MB,
process_physical_memory_low,
process_virtual_memory_low
from sys. dm_os_process_memory
```

Edit:

Regarding low virtual memory condition its coming because page file is not set correctly. You must use [This Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/12/14/what-is-the-page-file-for-anyway.aspx) and [This Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187877%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to configure appropriate value. [This link](http://www.amigabit.com/blog/how-to-fix-low-virtual-memory-problems-on-windows-7.html) will help to guide how to change

There can be many reasons for low virtual memory condition. The current workload which is running on OS is memory hungry and OS due to limited RAM has to use virtual memory for temp storage and ultimately its getting so much utilized that its giving warning. So you must check what all processes are running. Page file is adjusted as per memory committed if more memory is committed page file value changes  use below counters to determine appropriate value of page file

**Memory: Committed Bytes**     Number of bytes of virtual memory that has been committed.       This does not necessarily represent page file usage - it represents the amount of page file space that would be used if the process was completely made nonresident

**Memory: Commit Limit**    Number of bytes of virtual memory that can be committed without having to extend the paging files.

**Paging File: % Usage**    Percentage of the paging file committed

**Paging File: % Usage Peak**   Highest percentage of the paging file committed

Comment: Please use http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/12/14/what-is-the-page-file-for-anyway.aspx to set appropriate page file. Reason why virtual memory is being used more is may be current RAM on your system is not able to cope with workload and so its using virtual memory as temp storage and eventually using it so much that it is utilizing most of it hence warning message is coming